# Qual a diferença entre string.split(',') e string.rsplit(',') no python?

Tags: python, split

Ao utilizar essas linhas no terminal do python, não consegui encontrar diferença entre nenhuma delas. Pesquisei mas não encontrei nada sobre, ao menos em português. Qual seria a diferença entre elas ?

```
x = 'apple, banana, cherry'
x.split(',')
x.rsplit(',')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diferença aparece quando se passa o argumento opcional `maxsplit`. Ele determina o número máximo de divisões a se fazer.

No caso do `split`, o algoritmo começa da esquerda e os elementos do início da lista são divididos:

```
In [1]: '1-2-3-4-5-6'.split('-', maxsplit=3)
Out[1]: ['1', '2', '3', '4-5-6']
```

No caso do `rsplit`, o algoritmo começa da direita (do final da string) e as últimas ocorrências é que ficam:

```
In [2]: '1-2-3-4-5-6'.rsplit('-', maxsplit=3)
Out[2]: ['1-2-3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja esses exemplos

```
text = 'Essa, é, uma, string, de, teste' 
rs1 = text.rsplit(',',1)

rs1
['Essa, é, uma, string, de', ' teste']


rs2 = text.rsplit(',',2)

rs2
['Essa, é, uma, string', ' de', ' teste']

rs_1 = text.rsplit(',',-1)

rs_1
['Essa', ' é', ' uma', ' string', ' de', ' teste']
```

A diferença entre split e rsplit é que a "assinatura" de rsplit aceita o parametro , `max`, ou seja, o número máximo de splits a ser feito, então a sintaxe é `split(separador, max)`, se `max=-1` (default) todos os splits possíveis serão feitos. Conclusão: Se voce usar `string.rsplit()` sem o parametro `max`, o resultado será o mesmo de `string.split()`.